# Scheduling shutdown in layman's terms

Tags: sudo, shutdown, cron, schedule

I'm trying to schedule a shutdown for 10:30pm (22:30) each evening. I am fairly new to Ubuntu. In Windows 7, this was an extremely easy task. Apparently in Ubuntu this is a rather complicated task. I've tried to download Gnome-Schedule but to no avail...I'm stuck just trying to get the darn thing to compile! So scrap that idea for now I guess....

I've read several questions about scheduling shutdowns and people are saying to use sudo shutdown -h 22:30 or something of that sort, but that's a one-time thing isn't it? I need this to be a recurring, scheduled shut down to turn my machine off each evening.

So then I'm back to the Gnome-Schedule GUI because it looks like a reasonable facsimile of the Windows GUI. When I try to compile it, I'm told I need to do a cd to the directory it's in. Well, right now I have it in home/Documents/Scheduler, but if I do

cd /home/Documents/Scheduler , I get an error saying that no such directory exists. This is most frustrating...probably I'm just doing something that is a newbie mistake, but this is the first day I've ever used Ubuntu so much of it is quite esoteric to me at the moment.

Assuming that Gnome-Schedule is my best bet for getting a regularly scheduled shutdown time, what do I need to do to get this sucker compiled? Many thanks for your assistance!

Comment: `gnome-schedule` is also in the Ubuntu universe repo, shouldn't have to compile it. Should familiarize yourself with installing software on Ubuntu using the Software manager (I think that's it's name), or Synaptic, aptitude, or apt. And different software repos https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Fast forward to August 2018 and we find `gnome-schedule` has been deprecated.  The normal cron commands still work:  crontab -e to manage jobs, crontab -l to list yur jobs.  Here is the party line on the subject:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/942401/how-to-control-cron-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Answer (score 3):

You want `cron`, which is the age old unix daemon for running scheduled jobs.  Gnome-schedule only runs in your gui session as you, and so won't be able to run commands with `sudo` since you aren't there to type the password.

Insert a file in `/etc/cron.d/` to schedule a job to be automatically run as root at specified times.  To shutdown at 10:30 pm each evening, the line would be:

```
30 22 * * * root shutdown -h now
```

Comment: I'm not certain I know how to do what you're recommending. First of all, I don't know what "run as root" means. Second, I don't understand how "-h now" translates to 22:30 hours. Would I just need to substitute "-h 22:30" there?

Comment: Also, I've tried to save a new file in etc/cron.d but I keep getting an error stating that I do not have permissions necessary to save the file. Is this the "root" thing you were talking about? If so, how do I work around that?

Comment: @1John5vs7, root is the user that does not have limited permissions; it is who you become when you run `sudo` and is required to run `shutdown`.  The `shutdown` command is scheduled run at 22:30 hours, so at that time, you specify now.  You need to use `sudo` to gain permission to edit system directories, i.e. `sudo nano /etc/cron.d/shutdown` to fire up the friendly `nano` editor with root permission to edit that file.

Comment: Thank you, psusi, that is very helpful and helps me understand the problem a bit better. Where I'm still confused is this: I have opened "Scheduled Tasks" which was either something that was bundled with Ubuntu directly or was in the apps package that they recommend you download on a fresh install. At any rate, in that program, I've created a `crontab` task, set the date and time to `30 22 * * *` and set the command as `shutdown -h now`. Are you saying that what I'd need to do instead is make the command `sudo nano /etc/cron.d/shutdown -h now` instead? Thank you.

Comment: @1John5vs7, Umm... no.. I'm saying you need to not use "Scheduled Tasks" at all and instead you use `sudo nano /etc/cron.d/shutdown` to edit a text file in which you write the line telling `cron` to run `shutdown -h now` as the root user at the chosen time.

Comment: Ah ok. My apologies for the ignorance, but again, I've stated I am brand-spanking new to Ubuntu. I have now pieced together that you are asking me (I think) to run a terminal, and in terminal to type in `sudo nano /etc/cron.d/shutdown`. I have done that, and it takes me to the nano editor. However, once in there I am not certain what to do. Is this where I insert `30 22 * * * shutdown -h now`? If so, how do I save the file? I don't see an option for save & exit or anything similar to that.

Comment: @1John5vs7, The bottom line of the screen lists the important keys such as ^O to write the file and ^X to exit.  That is to say Control + X.

Comment: This is precisely the correct answer.  Use crontab -e to edit the crontab file to insert this exact line.  It is easy.  Here is a bit more no the subject:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/942401/how-to-control-cron-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts